# jQuery FancyBox Close, and Button Click Handling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I am developing `ASP.NET 4.0` application runs in Facebook App. I'am using `jQuery FancyBox` to show some PopUps. I can easily show modal, but when I try to close or try to handle which button (Yes/No) clicked, problems occur. Searched many sites, found many solutions, but nothing changed. For example, this is code which I use to show modal

This is HTML Part

```
<div id="uyariIki" class="uyariModal">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
         <tr>
       // Some Mesages here
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td align="center" valign="middle"><a class="modalTamam-button" href="#"  onclick='$.fancybox.close'>Tamam</a></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I used different codes on onclick event such as

```
$.fancybox.close()
```

OR

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

OR

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

But these are didnt work. When I hit "Tamam" button, LightBox is closing and suddenly showing again like an infinite loop or postback.

I also tried to close it from Javascript such as:

```
function CloseFancyBox() {
    $("#uyariIki").fancybox().trigger('close');
}
```

But ofcourse this one also didnt work :)

Checking http://fancybox.net/api to see options, `$.fancybox.close` is located in this site. But its not working.

So, how can I close `FancyBox`, when I click "Tamam" button on `FancyBox Modal`

Second question is; How can I handle which button pressed (Yes/No)? (I can provide codes of this modal)

I can provide another information if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Full source please, would like to see the relationships between the pieces.

Comment: which part you want to see? because source code is too long.

Comment: The part where you hook up the fancybox.

Comment: it sounds like any of the selectors in `class="modalTamam-button"` is bound to fancybox ... as @RubbleFord mentioned, show the script where you bind fancybox to a selector (class or ID).

Comment: You are linking to fancybox 1 API, but is there any chance that the fancybox you are using is fancybox 2 ( http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ )?

Answer (score 1):

You have written;

```
  <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a class="modalTamam-button" href="#"  onclick='$.fancybox.close'>Tamam</a>
  </td>
```

try:

`$.fancybox.close();`

or try this:

`javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this on button click event:-

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "close", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script>", "parent.$.fancybox.close() ;"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this inside aftershow call back:
Note: ('close') is the id of your button on which u want to perform close() function.

```js
 $('#close').click(function(e) {
                    $(".fancybox-close")[0].click();
                })
```